# Do split grenades inherit their properties?

Tags: borderlands-2

In Borderlands II, some grenades split after being thrown into multiple smaller grenades.

Say if the initial grenade had a `Homing` property, would the smaller grenades also home to nearby enemies after they spawned or is it only the first grenade that homes to enemies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, "bomblets" or released grenades have their own properties, though they will inherent the elemental type on their item card, and they behave in a specific way depending on the base type of grenade (MIRV/Transfusion).

Homing MIRV grenades still release plain bomblets that rise and fall in an arc, just like lobbed/longbow MIRVS. Similarly Transfusion grenades always release homing projectiles even if they aren't homing Transfusion grenades. There are however some legendary/unique grenades which have special properties applied to their bomblets that normal grenades do not, such as the Fuster Cluck, which drops bomblets as it's moving in the air rather than after detonation.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I could have sworn I remember bomblets homing in on enemies...

Comment: @SaintWacko sure you weren't using a Transfusion grenade? Transfusions always home in on targets like Transfusions in the first game

Comment: I'm sure I wasn't. Transfusion grenades just aren't as fun in BL2. I suppose I could be misremembering it, though. I'll have to check next time I'm playing.

Comment: @SaintWacko really? They work basically the same except not as underpowered and they have elemental effects. For bonus fun use Slag transfusions